# TreeVIew icons not displaying in MMC Snap-in on Windows XP

Tags: c#, treeview, windows-xp, mmc, snap-in

We have developed a User Interface as an MMC snap-in but we’re having issues displaying icons inside a Treeview on Windows XP.

Basically, icons (.ico) added to ImageLists of a TreeView are simply not visible on Windows XP. We researched on the internet and received some pointers. , like these –

1. http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/re-mmc-3-0-and-xp-icons-t2611897.html
   This suggest drawing a Bitmap using the ico file.
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965205(VS.85).aspx
   This is an MSDN resource that suggests a few points to note in this regard.
3. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.imagelist.aspx
   This MSDN resource has a note that requires us to add `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` and `Application.DoEvents()` just before `InitializeComponents()` - but since we are building an MMC snap-in, I cannot understand where to use these.

   This link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx#mmc
   has some information about this but it is for VC++ whereas our entire code is in C#

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround - Populate the SmallImageList in the constructor and you should get this working.